# Weird outline around rgba letter

Tags: css, google-chrome, rgba

I added a rgba color to a letter on a dark background and there is a very small white outline around it in Chrome (67). I forced a `outline: none` but nothing changed.

[image: weird outline]

```css
body {
 background: #575354;
}

span.letter-back{
  top:-40px;
  z-index: 1;

  color:rgba(237, 28, 36, 0.3);
  font-size:300px;
  font-weight:900;
  font-family: sans-serif;

  outline:none !important;
}
```

```html
<span class="letter-back">B</span>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What kind of element is using the `.letter-back` class?

Comment: try using rgb to define the color and set opacity to .3

Comment: @Wamadahama Its a span

Comment: @Xedret That worked! If you add your comment as a reply I'll mark it as the solution

Comment: @TheBird956 Just did, thanks.

Comment: Good fixes, seems to be a rendering issues with the browser / OS as I don’t see the outline in the snippet on Firefox / Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using rgb to define the color and set opacity to .3

```
span.letter-back {
 color:rgb(237, 28, 36);
 opacity: .3;
}
```

It renders differently than RGBA.

Answer (score 1):

This 'white border' is actually the browser trying to nicely render this large semi-transparent letter on gray. The colour you're seeing is actually in between gray and transparent dark red, and appears as a white glow.

I would try playing with these CSS properties:
[CSS text-rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-rendering)

They may have an effect on the output.

Aside from that, I would recommend choosing a non-transparent colour here in order to avoid any unpredictable appearance. Looks like this is #854246